# How to express among in chinese?

Tags: word-requests

I've encountered myself quite a few times trying to express the word among in chinese and the meaning that it carries, just like in these two senteces:

> He's vey popular among the students.
>
> Quite a few students have passed the exam, and I am among them.

How do I express this idea? For example, for the first one I would say: 他在学生们中很吃香的. Is it correct? Is it the best way to express what I am willing to express?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, sometimes you won't translate 'among', see your first sentence. Other times, 'among' will translate simply as 中, or a combination of 在 ... 中, like your second sentence. 在 ...  间 is also common, but there are other ways. Of course, exactly if and how 'among' is expressed will depend on the context.

1. He's very popular among the students.
   他很受学生（的）欢迎。
2. Quite a few students have passed the exam, and I am among them.
   相当多的学生通过了考试，我也在其中。

Edit: Reading this morning, I came across this:

国家文物局明确指出，“西市” 是隋唐丝绸之路的起点，要纳入申请世界文化遗产的名录当中。

纳入 ...当中 or just plain 当中, in my opinion, is "among", but I wouldn't translate it that way.

Comment: *Well, sometimes you won't translate 'among',*-- That's called "rephrasing". When you can't translate word for word and maintain the original meaning, you do have the option of rephrasing. But "among + noun" is not difficult to translate as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first translation is good and correct. It matches the words with English, and it sounds pretty natural. `吃香` is also a very good use of slang. It's just one way of speaking of the suggested answer - `他很受学生(的）欢迎` .

For the second sentence, I would say: `很多学生通过了考试，我也过了`

I think it's good that to have word-word translation, but the purpose I learn another language is to communicate, not to work as a translator, so I'm a little liberal in using words. I've seen many answers here try to match each word and I don't quite get it. If I learn a language that way, I probably will never be able to speak up. So what I'm trying to say is, focusing on the meaning not the word itself. Just like in English, you can say `i'm among them`, you can also say `i'm one of them` or `so did i!`